# Flutter GridView not showing when running on server

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, build

Here is my the GridView that I use in my app when I run it locally :
[image]

And here when I make build (flutter build web) and run it on a server :
[image]

I get this error in the browser's console:

> TypeError: Instance of 'minified:jO': type 'minified:jO' is not a
> subtype of type 'minified:fC' main.dart.js:11277     at Object.c
> (http://localhost/web/main.dart.js:10095:3) main.dart.js:11277     at
> Object.az8 (http://localhost/web/main.dart.js:10740:18)
> main.dart.js:11277     at iR.aMx [as a]
> (http://localhost/web/main.dart.js:10735:3) main.dart.js:11277     at
> eR.tq (http://localhost/web/main.dart.js:63249:6) main.dart.js:11277
> at tE.xS (http://localhost/web/main.dart.js:66379:58)
> main.dart.js:11277     at tE.ep
> (http://localhost/web/main.dart.js:66299:3) main.dart.js:11277     at
> tE.ep (http://localhost/web/main.dart.js:66408:3) main.dart.js:11277
> at eD.ul (http://localhost/web/main.dart.js:66063:3)
> main.dart.js:11277     at eD.eu
> (http://localhost/web/main.dart.js:66023:16) main.dart.js:11277     at
> eD.iZ (http://localhost/web/main.dart.js:66186:32)

**edit : I added the code of CardTest**

Here is the code of my GridView :

```
Column(
      children: [
        buildSubheadingText('Mes projets'),
        buildVerticalSpace(5.0),
        GridView.count(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          childAspectRatio: kIsWeb ? 4/1.3 : 1 /1.4,
          //physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: [
            CardTest(
          loadingPercent: 0.25, 
          title: 'Making History Notes', 
          subtitle: '20 hours progress', 
          dueDate: DateTime(2022, 4, 12)
        ),
```

CardTest(
loadingPercent: 0.25,
title: 'Making History Notes',
subtitle: '20 hours progress',
dueDate: DateTime(2022, 4, 12)
),
CardTest(
loadingPercent: 0.25,
title: 'Making History Notes',
subtitle: '20 hours progress',
dueDate: DateTime(2022, 4, 12)
)
)
],
);

Here is the code of CardTest widget :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CardTest extends StatelessWidget {

  final double loadingPercent;
  final String title;
  final String subtitle;
  final DateTime dueDate;

  CardTest({
    required this.loadingPercent,
    required this.title,
    required this.subtitle,
    required this.dueDate
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Flexible(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.amber,
        child : Column(
          children: [
            Text(loadingPercent.toString()),
            Text(title),
            Text(subtitle),
            Text(dueDate.toString()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is "buildCardItem" doing? Those are the ones crashing and why you see a gray part of the screen

Comment: Here is the code of a carditem : return CardItem(
      loadingPercent: 0.25,
      title: 'Medical App',
      subtitle: '9 hours progress',
      dueDate: DateTime(2022, 2, 1)
    );  when I use them outside the grid they work well, it's the grid causing the issue but I don't know why

Comment: You need to put the code updating your question as it can't be formatted here in the comments. And avoid shrinking your grid view, either put it on expandable or flexible widget when you have it inside a column or row.

Comment: Try deploying a version with `flutter build web --dart-define=Dart2jsOptimization=O0 --profile` to see the unobfuscated stacktrace

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla I added the modifications

Comment: @passsy I tried it, same result

Comment: @JS1 have you tried removing the "flexible" widget from the CardTest? You haven't set a min size to the column inside the card as well

Comment: @JS1 Make sure to clear your browser cache (try an incognito window) to see the unobfuscated stacktrace. The main.dart.js is most likely cached by the service-worker

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla thanks, getting rid of Flexible works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @MarianoZorrilla in the comments :

I simply had to remove the Flexible from my CardTest.